# Convert a Quote into a Backend Order

Tags: orders, workflow

Is there a **non programatic** way to convert an existing cart/quote into an order in a stock Magento CE system?  Stock Magento EE system?

If not, how are merchants handling the (seemingly common) problem of a customer service agent helping a customer complete an order over the phone or via chat support?  Does an extension exist the enable this sort of backend workflow?  Or is everyone programming their own?

Again, not looking for the code that would do this — I have that part covered.  I'm wondering if this feature is supported in Magento, and if not, how the community is handling this common feature request.

Comment: Maybe it makes sense to create an order from Admin Panel? http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/creating-orders-in-admin-panel

Comment: You mean like to get a non complete quote and make it an order?

Comment: @PetarDzhambazov Yes — basically the "create order" button on the backend, but have the order UI automatically load an incomplete quote.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the backend you can go to Customer > Manage Customer > Select YOUR customer

then at the top "Create order" and then select the store view and you create a new order and have on the left side the cart of the customer.

Then you can add the products you want to put into the order from the cart and create the order.

Comment: Useful, thanks, +1!  However, it's the "add the products you want to put into the order" part I'm trying to circumvent.  If the customer already did this, it's super annoying that they have to redo it.

Comment: You don't have to redo it, if they're signed in. [screenshot](http://f.cl.ly/items/0c2J422J3M301V1Y0O3y/Screen%20Shot%202014-02-28%20at%2020.42.32.png)

Answer (score 2):

To create order for registered customer you can go to Admin -> Sales -> Orders and press "Create New Order", then you will be asked to select customer's account against which the order will be created (you can also create new customer from here). Alternatively you can use method described by Fabian.

The only data transferred to an order are products which you can pick from customer's cart,  wishlist, recently ordered items, products in comparison list, recently compared or recently viewed items.

The nice thing about selecting products from customer's cart is that they preserve original configuration (i.e. custom options or configurable attributes), their price is also updated to the current value. More on the subject could be found at http://ronwe.com/ecommerce/magento/convertquote1/